# Spinner causes error when using custom style

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles

First things first, I'm pretty new in Android programming and Stackoverflow has helped a lot so far as have other websites. However for the problem I'm having now I have not found a solution yet. The app I'm creating crashes with the following error:

```
AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #19: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5319)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5271)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.java:4471)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:296)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1017)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2120)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12751)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2558)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

First I checked the obvious, and checked all my layout files that I used `layout_height` on everything and I do use it everywhere. So I researched more and have discovered what is happening.

On http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ I created a custom style and downloaded the zip-file and I unzipped that into my project (btw I'm using Android-Studio). When running the app it styles just fine with the content from the zip-file.

When adding a spinner to the layout and setting an `ArrayAdapter` on it causes my app to crash with the stacktrace above. Using `setAdapter` is important within the issue because when omitting or commenting it the error does not occur but then the spinner is also not populated but it's arrow does show. Reverting the style to the default style causes the app to work as intended without problems. This behavior has been seen both on an emulator as on a real device, on the latter moments later it often even reboots.

I also created a test-app to see if it isn't anything else in my app that is causing the issue but also in this test-app I have noticed the same behavior. Any help in resolving this issue is very much appreciated. Below is the code from that test-app.

The layout file `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testspinnertheme.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The java file `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.testspinnertheme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] strings = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> aaString = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, strings);
        aaString.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDistance.setAdapter(aaString);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The manifest file `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testspinnertheme" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testspinnertheme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The following file with the styles (`styles_test.xml`) is actually created by the above mentioned website

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File created by the Android Action Bar Style Generator

 Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_test</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Test</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_test</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_test</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_test</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_test</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_test</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_test</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_test</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_test</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_test</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Test" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_test</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Test.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Test</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Test</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. When I try to set the adapter it crashes with the same error as yours. When I use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` it works. When I use my own xml file with a simple textview (`layout_width`, `layout_height` included) it crashes. No matter what values I assign to those parameters. I'm desperate.

Comment: I solved it. After a few hours of debug. I accidentally had two layout xml files with the same name in my project. One was in my library and one was in my app layout folder. The one in the app layout folder didn't have width, height set. So I just deleted it. Now it picks up the right one from my library.

Comment: Isn't it fantastic when one can solve their own issues ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have been trying some stuff to get this resolved and I succeeded. Now I have to admit that I don't know the details and specifics as to why it works now but here is what I did.

In the `onCreate` method in the java file `MainActivity.java` I changed the following lines:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aaString = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, strings);
aaString.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I changed those lines to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aaString = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, strings);
aaString.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

Maybe somebody can explain via comments as in why this change resolves the problem.
As for now I'll accept my own answer if that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? Once I was getting this error and I solved it by just cleaning the project

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, I tried cleaning and rebuilding but it does NOT solve the issue.